# Most efficient grep method

Tags: grep

Currently I am grepping data from a file containing any of the following:

```
342163477\|405760044\|149007683\|322391022\|77409125\|195978682\|358463993\|397650460\|171780277\|336063797\|397650502\|357636118\|168490006...............
```

This list is longer and contaings ~700 different values.

What is the most efficient way of extracting it? I can chop it in parts of 10/20/50/100... Or are there other unix methods? This grep is piped to python for further analysis which goes fast enough.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking, can you elaborate?  Your source file has a single line with lots of values in it?  Or the text you've included is what you're looking for in the source file?

Answer (score 2):

Put all those numbers in a file, each on its own line, then use `grep` with `-f` or `--file=` switch:

```
grep -f filewithcodestosearchfor filetosearchin
```

Comment: Hmm the first few runs it seemed faster but that might be human interpretation. Need to run time on it as well. Is it also possible to delete the grepped lines from the file?

Comment: Is that actually faster or just more convenient to work with?

Comment: @Marco, it would be faster with `--fixed-strings` aka `-F` aka `fgrep`

Comment: @poige The performance increase comes from `-F` (which is not mentioned in this answer) and not from `-f`, right?

Comment: @Marco, why I suggested `-f` is to avoid Jasper's initial intention of using multiple `grep` calls, each with a subset of the code list. `grep`, especially GNU `grep`, is strong in optimization, is better to just let it work instead of spoonfeeding it. Of course, @poige's `-F` still improves a lot. http://pastebin.com/P8tTEmie

Comment: @manatwork, can you also make those tests with `--mmap`?

Comment: @poige, the only difference is a warning: “grep: the --mmap option has been a no-op since 2010”. The times are the same as without `--mmap`.

Comment: @manatwork, 10x! It's strange a bit, what's your distro?

Comment: @poige, it's [Frugalware GNU/Linux](http://frugalware.org/) and used GNU `grep` 2.14.

Answer (score 2):

No need to put them in a file, you can do:

```
grep -F '342163477
405760044
149007683
322391022
77409125
195978682
358463993
397650460
171780277
336063797
397650502
357636118
168490006' file
```

as well, which is just as portable/standard (as using `grep -Ff`, `\|` in `grep` BREs is **not** standard/portable).

Also, what's the real question? Do you want to get the lines that contain those numbers or to know which of those numbers appear in the file? Is the file sorted? Is there one number per line in the file?...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the `--mmap` flag?

From man:

> ```
>    --mmap If possible, use the mmap(2) system call to read input, instead
>           of the default read(2) system call.  In some situations, --mmap
>           yields better performance.  However, --mmap can cause undefined
>           behavior (including core dumps) if an input file shrinks while
>           grep is operating, or if an I/O error occurs.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As poige mentions in a comment to another answer, use `grep -F`/`fgrep` if you can. This treats any regex characters as literals. You can still get the effect of alternation by combining this with the `-f file` option, and putting your patterns in file, one pattern to a line.

If you need your patterns to include regex, then try limiting yourself to classic ERE syntax, and use `grep -E`/`egrep`. Classic ERE syntax doesn't include backreferences, so no patterns of the form `...(pat)...\1...` Potentially this may use a DFA to perform the match, and be more efficient. But that depends on your egrep implementation. More discussion of this is [here](http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Regex#POSIX_regex). Note that some egrep implementations like Gnu's will accept patterns with backreferences; but when matching those patterns the efficiency advantage mentioned here will certainly not be present.

I mention the `egrep` optimization for theoretical interest, and because it'd be worth testing to see if it helps in your intended use. I'd guess that, as manatwork says, Gnu's grep engine is better at figuring out how to optimize than you are.

Comment: It's already been said in existent answer, why making dups, just to make bonuses? That's crumby.